# three js is throwing _canvas is null error

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I have some JS code through three.js for my website. I want two canvas to managed with separate CSS command( one is {position:relative}; another is {position:fixed} ) for different tabs. But it is throwing that error. Why? Help me please.

HTML code;

```
  <canvas id="c1"></canvas>
  <canvas id="c2"></canvas>
```

JS code;
c1>

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
camera.position.z = 30;
// camera.position.x = -15;

const canvas = document.querySelector('#c1');
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas, alpha: true});

renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    renderer.setSize( width, height);
    camera.aspect = width/height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
 })
```

//c2's codes is same c1.

CSS;

```
#c1{ 
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 position:relative;
 z-index:1;
 }  //same c2
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your canvas binding isn't correct -- it should work if you try this:

```js
    // Setup renderer
    let renderer = this.renderer = new WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true });
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.outputEncoding = sRGBEncoding;
    this.canvasRef.nativeElement.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // Setup scene
    let scene = this.scene = new Scene();

    // Setup camera
    let camera = this.camera = new PerspectiveCamera();
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
```

Note: You will need to prefix most of these functions depending on how you're importing THREE.

Comment: It doesn't work. Actually, my codes working what i want in first view page but if i click to assigned canvas pages it throwing error with "_canvas is null" after 2 second

Comment: in sum, i want to manage the each canvas with css position command.

Comment: The error gets thrown when you try switching 'tabs' right?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, Okay. I solved it.

No need the canvas command in css page. I just added these commands...

```
renderer.domElement.style.position = 'fixed';
renderer.domElement.style.top = 0;
renderer.domElement.style.zIndex = '1';
```